How basic wireless electricity transmission circuit works?
In the circuit below  because of the DC voltage source  there will be no flux change on steady state of the circuit so how the LED still stays turned on  if magnetic flux is not changing and  no voltage induced on secondary?


please add a link to the source of the image ... add it to your post, not in a comment

better still, use the built-in schematic editor to draw the schematic and click save and insert when done


In the circuit below because of the DC voltage source there will be no flux change on steady state of the circuit ...

But the circuit doesn't have a steady state.

... so how the LED still stays turned on if magnetic flux is not changing ...

The magnetic flux is changing.


On power-on Q1 is off.
A small current, limited by R1, will flow up from the coil centre-tap, through R1 and Q1's base turning it on. Current will now flow from the centre-tap through Q1's C-E.
The "downward" current flow will induce a negative voltage at the top of the coil. This will turn off Q1.
The process repeats.


... and no voltage induced on secondary?

Voltage is induced on the secondary.
Note that the LED doesn't stay on. It flashes at the oscillator frequency.

The transmitter you show is not a DC circuit, but an oscillator.

So how do you switching operation mode of transistor without PWM signal

@serkan that's a basic oscillator circuit. Current flows to base. Transistor turns on. Pulls current through collector. Which pulls current away from base. Which turns off the transistor. And the cycle starts over.
